# Compute C1, C2, C3, C4, C5

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question

C1 = 0, C$n$ = C$\lfloor n /2\rfloor$ + $n^2$ for all $n > 1$

Compute C1, C2, C3, C4

So what I did is:

C2 = C$\lfloor 2/2\rfloor + 2^2$  = 1 + 4 = 5 -- but that is wrong because the answer is supposed to be 4...

C4 = C$\lfloor 4/2\rfloor + 4 ^2$ = 2 + 16 = 18 -- but that is wrong as well, because the answer is supposed to be 20.

Am i not doing something right? Because I do know that Floor of 1 is 1...

Comment: Did you mean to use the recurrence $C_n = C\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + n^2$ instead of $+n$?

Comment: @gt6989b yes, sorry made the edit

Comment: Note your recurrence is defined for $n>1$ and a value is given for $C_0$. What is $C_1$?

Comment: "C1=0... Compute C1" Are you sure?

Comment: The floor of 1 is 1, but $C_1=0$, not $C_1=1$.

Comment: Likely, $C_0=0$ and recurrence is defined for $n \geq 1$. Could the OP please specify? Thank you.

Comment: By the way, once $C_2$ is wrong, you need not compute $C_4$.  After the boat has sunk you can stop paddling.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, i figured out that i missed C1 = 0

Comment: FYI, In the title, you asked for $C5$ too, but not in the question's body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $C2 = C\lfloor2/2\rfloor+2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5$ -- but that is wrong because the answer is supposed to be 4...

On this line, for instance, you say that $C\lfloor 2/2 \rfloor = 1$, but $C\lfloor 2/2 \rfloor = C1 = 0$.